# Reversing a diagonal search

Tags: java, arrays, diagonal

I am starting with Java and I was wondering how could you reverse a diagonal search like the one shown in the picture but from bottom left to right or from right top to bottom left.

[image]

The code for the diagonal search shown in the picture is :

```js
// top-left to bottom-right - green diagonals

for (int rowStart = 0; rowStart < rowMax - 4; rowStart++) {
  int count = 0;
  int row, col;
  for (row = rowStart, col = 0; row < rowMax && col < colMax; row++, col++) {
    if (gridTable[row][col] == player) {
      count++;
      if (count >= 4) return 1;
    } else {
      count = 0;
    }
  }
}

// top-left to bottom-right - red diagonals

for (colStart = 1; colStart < colMax - 4; colStart++) {
  count = 0;
  int row, col;
  for (row = 0, col = colStart; row < rowMax && col < colMax; row++, col++) {
    if (gridTable[row][col] == player) {
      count++;
      if (count >= 4) return 1;
    } else {
      count = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of `gridTable[row][col]`, and how `row` and `col` are incremented during the search?  Write down a list of the values of `row` and `col` that would be needed to perform the search left-to-right bottom-to-top.